# How to calculate the value of compensation network of DC DC converter

Tags: control-system

I am designing a circuit to boost voltage from 5V to 9V.I came across various kind of Switch regulator from TI. I don't know how to calculate the R-C value of compensation network.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to be more specific than this if you want a proper answer. Show some effort, that way people will know where you stand knowledge-wise and will be able to match their answers to your understanding. Maximize the power transfer, give us your impedance and let us match it.

Comment: Normally I would say "The datasheet will explain using the loop gain of the regulator", but I have seen TI datasheets of compensated regulators and I'm quite convinced they don't know how to do that either.

Comment: Loop compensation is a subject in its own right; the specifics depend on both the type of converter (current mode or voltage mode) and the specifics of your application. Provide the specifics (Vin, Vout, Iout) and the particular part you wish to use and we might be able to assist you.

Comment: look at some data sheets for Linear and Maxim parts, they might be more hand-holding than the TI ones. The principles will be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I had referred the datasheet but to calculate the value of compensation network is very difficult and confusing. It tells about transfer function, bode plot and system stability.

Can anyone help me to understand to decide Gain Margin and Phase margin for a stable system ? How to visualize this concept.

Thanks in Advance !!